# computer shows two internet connections

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection

I've recently purchased a new laptop and have noticed that my home network connection sometimes shows up twice and it never did that before.  I'm just not sure if it's my new laptop with Windows 8 or what's going on.

For example:

original network connection name:  scoobydoo2
what is occasionally showing:  scoobydoo2 2

its like it's a copy but I've no idea where it's coming from.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have both a wireless connection and a wired one?  Could be that you're just seeing one connect over the other.  It creates a 2nd network name in windows sometimes to account for that.

Comment: Nope, we just have wireless.

Comment: What version of windows is it?  I seem to recall seeing stuff like that happen before but I can't remember what OS it was.  It certainly wasn't something malicious though.  I just can't remember exactly why it was happening in my case.  Do you connect to more than one modem/router sometimes?  That could be the issue possibly.

Comment: It's normal.  Mines up to showing a 4 at the end now.  If you change your network password and/or re-add the network the name gets incremented.  It's not connecting to two networks, it's connecting to the second instance of the network.